# Can't use IFERROR

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Am using a bloomberg Add-in, and I get an error that shows #N/A N/A and I've also got some #NUM! errors.

IFERROR doesn't work because #N/A N/A isn't a standard excel error.

Is there any excel formula I can use to ignore errors, maybe using if or something?

Comment: Sorry, but your question isn't very clear. Can you give us an example? IFERROR understands all error codes (#N/A and #NUM! included)

Comment: yes but #N/A N/A is an error code that is not a standard excel error.

Comment: If it's not an error, what do you expect the output to be?  Is it a number, text, or something else?  There may be a function to check for that rather than checking for errors.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are using Excel 2010 so try

`=IFERROR(IF(A1="#N/A N/A","No","Yes),"No")`

or in any version

`=IF(ISERROR(A1),"No",IF(A1="#N/A N/A","No","Yes))`

Replace the "No" values (there are two) with what you want to happen for "errors" and "Yes" with what you want to happen for other entries.

....or shorter but more opaque....

`=IF(COUNT(1/(A1<>"#N/A N/A")),"Yes","No")`

Comment: If your output is just number, you can shorten it to `=iferror(--A1,"No")`

Comment: Hey Thomas! Nice one

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is:

=IFERROR(A1/1,"na")

Dividing #N/A N/A by 1 results in an error that Excel recognizes and hence iferror starts to work